# Location-based events web service?

Tags: webapp-rec

I'm looking for a web service displaying events in a specific geographic area. 
For example I select my district and I see the map with all events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use http://simplegeo.com/ and I have used http://www.maxmind.com. Maxmind's product is more geared towards scalability and absolutely minimizing the amount of time it takes to return a query, where as Simple Geo is geared towards being absolutely simple to implement and returning a rich amount of data for a given ip address.

I gave the same answer on: [App/API that takes in IP and spits out (longitude,latitude) coords or timezone](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/13524/app-api-that-takes-in-ip-and-spits-out-longitude-latitude-coords-or-timezone/13525#13525)