# App/API that takes in IP and spits out (longitude,latitude) coords or timezone

Tags: geolocation, time-zone

I'm looking for an app or API that allows me to input an IP.  The app or API should spit out one of the following things:

- A coordinate pair (longitude, latitude)
- A timezone (preferably UTC integer format)

Services that output a city/town are not sufficient for this particular application.

Comment: I assume by "IP" you mean "IP address" and not "Intellectual Property" or some other abbreviation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use http://simplegeo.com/ and I have used http://www.maxmind.com. Maxmind's product is more geared towards scalability and absolutely minimizing the amount of time it takes to return a query, where as Simple Geo is geared towards being absolutely simple to implement and returning a rich amount of data for a given ip address.

Comment: SimpleGeo will allow us to approximate a location.  Works well enough.  Thanks!